# Permanent Cookie Contains Sensitive Session Information

Tags: security

I have a cookie question in regards to a security scan (via IBM Rational AppScan) conducted on a drupal(7.43) site. The security scan failed with the following error: (Permanent Cookie Contains Sensitive Session Information) is POSITIVE on: http://site-name/user/login?ModPagespeed=noscript (cookie = SESSa020b17496f7fb76f92dd28c8d8341be).

How to resolve this?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers :) I'm afraid none of the questions you're asking at the moment are in topic here, they're all general security related questions. The organisation that provided you with the scan results will be able to give you details of each problem, and let you know the general fix for each. If any of those require changes to Drupal, not just the web server config, we'll be able to help here, but we'll need to know the specifics of what you're trying to change. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your app scanner is alerting you that cookie session data is being sent over an insecure channel (http://site-name/user/login?ModPagespeed=noscript) and is susceptible [session hijacking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_hijacking).

One way to resolve this is to force your website to use HTTPS only, thus preventing anyone from sniffing out session data.